# Matlab Source Control Git and SVN

Tags: git, matlab, svn, version-control

I am fairly new to source control, and I've played around with Git and SVN integration in Matlab. Everything seems to do what I am looking forward, however, is it possible to have a copy of the pushed file saved on the remote repository? Or, if an earlier version of the file is already on the remote repo, can I save/overwrite it with the pushed changes?

Thanks,
Leon

Comment: This is exactly what’s already happening.

Comment: But when i go into my remote repo, the .m file that I've pushed doesn't have the changes that I've made on my local repo.

Comment: When using git, you have to `add` your changes to the index, create a `commit` in your local repository and finally `push` them to the remote repository. You should see your changes, then.

Comment: I see the changes as part of a branch, but I can't view the changes when I open the .m file in notepad.

Comment: Are you sure you’re looking at the right branch? If you’re successfully committing and pushing your changes then the only reason you wouldn’t see them is because you’re looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

In your local repo, if you change a .m file (such as `test.m`), you should commit your local changes and then push the changes to remote repo by below commands:

```
# Assume change test.m in local master branch
git add test.m
git commit -m 'change the test.m file'
git push origin master
```

Then you will fine the test.m file is updated in remote `master` branch.
More detail about git VCS, you can refer [Recording Changes to the Repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository) in git book.